# Consulta basica sobre forEach

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

Estoy practicando en JS para mejorar mi nivel hiper basico y estoy recorriendo con un foreach un objeto JSON para intentar generar unos li. El tema es que no logro hacer que me genere tantos li como contenido hay en el JSON solo me genera uno y es el ultimo.

Aca esta mi HTML

```
 <div class="destination-selection mt-4">
                    <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center destination-list">
                        <li class="destination-button" id="destination-but" >Hola</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Este es mi codigo JS

```
  const destButton = document.getElementById("destination-but")
  console.log(destButton)

  Object.entries(destinations).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(destinations)
    destButton.innerHTML = value.name
  })
```

Y les dejo foto de mi consola. Donde ahi se puede ver que solo me genera un li con el texto Titan. Cuando yo quiero los otros 3 tambien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En que estoy fallando ?

Comment: El problema es que estás sobre escribiendo el valor de tu `li`. No estás generando uno nuevo por cada entrada de tu objeto. Saludos

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, la variable `destButton` está en el `outer scope` del callback pasado a `forEach`, por lo tanto es accesible desde dentro del mismo. Tu primer comentario es erróneo.

Comment: No entiendo, adentro del foreach no deberia generar tantos li como posiciones del objeto?

Comment: `innerHtml` no genera `li`, sólo cambia el contenido del elemento. Para generar un elemento puedes bien concatenar cadenas o mejor crear elementos con [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) y luego añadirlos al `ul` con [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Ojo, el atributo `id` debe ser único por elemento, es decir, no puede haber `id` repetido en tu documento HTML

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tu comentario nuevamente está mal. Pero no entraré en discusiones.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que no estas organizando tu código o lo que quieres lograr no va acorde a lo que tienes en el código y todo eso se debe a una pobre investigación.

Para agregar elementos hay varias formas de hacerlo:

- agregar un Nodo/elemento Hijo a un nodo padre.
- agregar un Nodo/elemento Hermano a un nodo existente.

Incluso hay otros métodos pero solo trabajaremos con estos dos:

***A. Agregar un Nodo/elemento Hijo a un nodo padre.***

El nodo padre en este caso sería el ul y como este no tiene un atributo `id` o `name`, utilizaremos el buscados por clases que nos devuelve un objeto, dentro del objetos seleccionaremos el `elemento` 0 que es donde se encuentra nuestro nodo a utilizar, entonces trabajaremos creando con javascript vanilla el elemento `li` al que le inyectaremos el texto/html con `innerHTML` como el elemento lo hemos creado de forma programatica aun no existe en el `html` asi que debemos inyectarlo al `DOM` con  `appendChild` lo cual hara que se agregue como el ultimo hijo del nodo padre.

[Link Documentacion 1](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) /
[Link Documentacion 2](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

**Codigo de ejemplo:**

```js
const nodoPadre = document.getElementsByClassName("destination-list");
  
const destinations = {"0":{"name":"li1"},"1": {"name":"li2"},"2": {"name":"li3"}};

Object.entries(destinations).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = value.name
  nodoPadre[0].appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<div class="destination-selection mt-4">
  <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center destination-list">
    <li class="destination-button" id="destination-but" >Hola</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***B. Agregar un Nodo/elemento Hermano a un nodo existente.***

En este caso El nodo padre no se utiliza directamente, si no, el elemento hermano, como este elemento tiene un atributo `id` utilizaremos un `selector` por id, estos nos devuelve directamente el nodo, ya que los id deben ser `unicos` en el `DOM`, entonces trabajaremos creando con javascript vanilla el elemento `li` al que le inyectaremos el texto/html con `innerHTML` como el elemento lo hemos creado de forma programatica aun no existe en el `html` asi que debemos injectarlo al `DOM` la forma de hacerlo sera mediante una pseudo navegacion utilizando `parentNode` para ubicarnos temporalmente en el elemento padre y luego `insertBefore` para agregarlo al DOM; pasamos como segundo parametro null para que sea agregado al final.

[Link Documentacion 3](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-insertafter/)

**Codigo de ejemplo:**

```js
const nodoHermano = document.getElementById("destination-but");
  
const destinations = {"0":{"name":"li1"},"1": {"name":"li2"},"2": {"name":"li3"}};

Object.entries(destinations).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = value.name
  nodoHermano.parentNode.insertBefore(li,null);
})
```

```html
<div class="destination-selection mt-4">
  <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center destination-list">
    <li class="destination-button" id="destination-but" >Hola</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```